# R: Extract data from several files based on X,Ys

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df` in `R` containing X, Y UTM coordinates. The sample data looks like this:

```
ID   X        Y
1    333229   6580393
2    333229   6580500
3    333229   6581500
4    325889   6584200
...
```

The hourly wind speed and wind direction data for above (and other) X, Ys is located in a directory containing meteorological data of many years (1995 - 2011, more than 100,000 .dat files). Each file, for example, named as `"hourly_333229_6580393_2010.dat"` contains hourly data of a single year like this:

```
Day   Month   Year   hour   w_speed   w_dir
1     1       2010   1      5.02      247.55
2     1       2010   2      2.6       320.12
3     1       2010   3      3         315.25
```

From this directory, I would like to extract hourly wind speed and direction data for above X,Ys and for the period 1 May 2005 - 31 July 2005 in the following manner:

```
ID   Year   Month   Day   hour   X        Y         w_speed  w_dir
1    2005   5       1     1      333229   6580393   2.01     120
2    2005   5       1     2      333229   6580393   5.2      370
3    2005   5       1     3      333229   6580393   1.5      115
...
```

How could I achieve this using `R` in an optimized way? Any help/suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is common to work with .TIFF or .nc files when it comes to climate-data. If you have these at hand i would recommend following Santander MetGroups approach: https://github.com/SantanderMetGroup/climate4R

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion, would have a look for sure.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest creating a function for the purpose of opening each dat-file. Please replace the `read.table` function by the function you use for opening the dat-files. In this case, the function contains both coordinates and the months to which respect it filters the dataframe as arguments. Arguments could however be extended by year and days for instance. To keep it simple I only included months.

```
open_dat <- function(X, Y, left, right) {

dat <- read.table(paste("hourly", X, Y, "2005.dat", sep = "_"), 
           header=TRUE) %>% as.tibble()
dat$X <- X
dat$Y <- Y

dat %>% filter(between(Month, left, right))

}
```

Then, we can apply the function to the dataframe that contains X and Y for the days that are between May and July (numbers 5 and 7):

```
full_df <- map2_dfr(df$X, df$Y, open_dat, left = 5, right =7)
```